# Piwik statitics about all websites

Tags: api, matomo

Is it possible to use the Piwik-API with all Websites, not just for a single one?

What i want to do is get a mean value of used browsers. I can do this for a single website like this:

```
?module=API&method=UserSettings.getBrowser&idSite=1&period=day&date=last10&format=rss
```

If i just remove `idSite=1` i get an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify all sites using `idSite=all`, you can also specify multiple sites by separating the ids with commas `idSite=1,2,4,5`.

The resulting output is given per idSite wrapped in an extra `<results>` tag, so whereas before you had

```
<result>
    <row>
        <label>Chrome 14.0</label>
        <nb_uniq_visitors>13</nb_uniq_visitors>
        ...
    </row>
    <row>
        <label>Chrome 13.0</label>
        <nb_uniq_visitors>13</nb_uniq_visitors>
        ...
    </row>
    ...
</result>
```

You now get

```
<results>
    <result idSite="2">
        <row>
            <label>Chrome 14.0</label>
            <nb_uniq_visitors>13</nb_uniq_visitors>
            ...
        </row>
        <row>
            <label>Chrome 13.0</label>
            <nb_uniq_visitors>13</nb_uniq_visitors>
            ...
        </row>
        ...
    </result>
    <result idSite="3">
        <row>
            <label>Chrome 14.0</label>
            <nb_uniq_visitors>13</nb_uniq_visitors>
            ...
        </row>
        <row>
            <label>Chrome 13.0</label>
            <nb_uniq_visitors>13</nb_uniq_visitors>
            ...
        </row>
        ...
    </result>
    ...
</results>
```

This does mean that any aggregating for your mean value will have to be done once you get the data but this should be relatively trivial.